# SharePoint 2010 export to excel:Cannot connect to server at this time

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, excel

While exporting any document library in a SharePoint 2010 web application , getting following error:

> "Cannot connect to server at this time. Changes to your data cannot be
>   saved."

Export to excel work fine in all other web applications in the same SharePoint 2010 environment.

Tried changing security settings in IE but no luck.

Comment: Add SP-server (URL Root collection) to Local Intranet in settings IE. Your file is create in 64 bit Office or 32?

Comment: Thanks but this is also not working. There are folders in document library which contain documents but not sure which version were they created.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps:

Open Excel.

Go to "Data" tab from top menu.

Click on "From Web" from the menu items.

Connect your site with this.

Import the data.

Now go back to the IE and export List (which you were doing previously).

The List will be exported.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c779151e-681b-4d5b-a43f-034c7f2b8bad/excel-cannot-connect-to-sharepoint-list?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: I already tried this but still the same issue.